# How to reset BIOS Password on Acer Nitro/AN515-51

Tags: bios

Already tried CMOS with no success. Tried the online password sites with the key it gives me after failure to enter the password, but no dice.

Comment: You will have to ask Acer for the master password or send it to a facility that can reset it. I have never found an acer master password generator.

Comment: Maybe check YouTube such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scpy4jH6HY4 or find the manual for the specific make and model e.g.  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/C1kocOuHIiS.pdf . . . Wasn't sure if you could disconnect CMOS battery for a few minutes and jump and pins on the mobo or press a reset button on board, etc.

Comment: The site https://bios-pw.org/ worked for me today on Acer Nitro Aspire VN7 571

Comment: Absolutely stuck on the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of methods, including disconnecting my cmos battery, but the only one works perfectly for bios password 10 digits, totally free:

[enter link description here](https://let-def.github.io/insydious/)

I hope it works for you because I  waste to much time trying to solve it!

Answer (score -1):

Yes to this link for Acer Nitro Gaming laptop

I don't think it worked 6 months ago and then I tried it today and it worked.

Weird

https://let-def.github.io/insydious/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.